# Best practice to implement sending message to custom groups in SignalR

Tags: signalr

I am developing a real time multiplayer game using SignalR. The message delivery logic is not very simple which I could not handle it by using Groups.

For example, one message will be delivered to users with some custom property equals to some dynamic value. It means the target audiance can not be handled by

```
Clients.All
Clients.AllExcept
```

I have a mapping class something like this:

```
public class Player
{
  public dynamic Client { get; set; }

  public string ConnectionId { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Somehow I do detect all my audiences in a List object.

What is the best way to send message to everyone in the list? Enumerating through list and calling

```
        foreach (var loopPlayer in players)
        {
            player.Client.sendMessage(message);
        }
```

Or

```
        List<string> ids = new List<string>();
        foreach (var loopPlayer in players)
        {
            ids.Add(item.ConnectionId.ToString());
        }

        Clients.Clients(ids).sendMessage(message);
```

My concern about the first one is, it will serialize the message every time. About the second one, I don't know how it is working behind the scene.

The both approach is working but I am concerning about performance and trying to find the best practice. Or which any other approach I might use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, enumerating over list of clients serialize message each and every time (and store those serialized messages in internal buffers etc etc). If message is same, this is unnecessary CPU\memory overhead. 
`Clients.Clients(ids)` serializes message only once so performance vise, its definitely way to go.

*The message delivery logic is not very simple which I could not handle it by using Groups. For example, one message will be delivered to users with some custom property equals to some dynamic value.*

Groups work in scaleout scenario out of the box which is huge benefit if you ever find yourself in need to scaleout. So maybe try to find some way to simplify "group assigment logic" even at cost of delivering some messages to more clients and doing "filtering" client side...

Comment: Thanks for yor reply. For example I will send message to 10 clients but in my group there are more than 10 people in the group. You mean, send message to all of them and ignore it on the client side? Which is more expensive you think? Sending less message by doing custom filtering, sending more message without filtering and using group?

Comment: Well it's tradeoff. Sending messages to more clients ("broader" groups) -> more network traffic vs less CPU\memory pressure. Im not able to make any decision because i don't know actual numbers (no. of clients\resources available to you\message rate). I just think that groups are good for scaleout (because it works across all servers) + very conservative regarding CPU\memory.
[Here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-502) is very good in-depth video about scaling SignalR - really usefull...

Comment: And because you are creating the game, you can also find useful [Shootr](http://shootr.signalr.net/) which is multiplayer game implemented using SignalR - source code provided...